# JQuery animate div from right to left with smoothness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I have created page, where in the beginning it will show the black screen and from right to left the main screen will be visible, I am tried to achieve using jQuery animate, it seems to be working fine but there is no smoothness. I tried with CSS transition but no luck

Can somebody please suggest how to add smoothness, screen which is pushing to left should have smoothness and slow

Here is the [JSfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/tsq001g4/)

**EDIT** I have created a video to show how its showing in my computer:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvfxI84Bzt4&feature=youtu.be

Thanks

```js
var winw = $(window).width();
var winh = $(window).height();
var main = $('.mc-root');

$(main).animate({ right: '0' }, 900 );
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.main-outer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mc-root {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  transition: all 3s linear;
  right:-100%;
  
}
.leftcol {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.leftcol > p {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.rightcol {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.rightcol > p {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-outer">
  <div class="mc-root">
    <div class="leftcol">
      <p>NAV</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcol">
      <p>MAIN Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The animation looks smooth. No stutter or lagging. What do you mean by smoothness?

Comment: It looks smooth to me. I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Looks good to me too. I'm voting to close because the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: Using CSS `transform:translate` is usually smoother looking than using `left`/`right`: https://jsfiddle.net/tsq001g4/3/

Comment: @Fran this is how its looking in my screen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvfxI84Bzt4&feature=youtu.be there is no smoothness

Comment: I can't watch youtube or see images from shared image sites where I am, sorry :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, in my opinion is more smooth, the trick is in the timing and in the duration,

if you don't think that my solution is smooth enough, you can just change the function or the duration

```js
var winw = $(window).width();
var winh = $(window).height();
var main = $('.mc-root');

$(main).animate({ right: '0' }, 900 );
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.main-outer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.mc-root {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  right:-100%;
  
}
.leftcol {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.leftcol > p {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.rightcol {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.rightcol > p {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-outer">
  <div class="mc-root">
    <div class="leftcol">
      <p>NAV</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcol">
      <p>MAIN Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks the same to me as the original code, only faster. They both look smooth here.

Comment: there is an change in the function, is more smooth to me

Comment: Your answer isn't wrong. It's just subjective, hence the answer to the question might be based more on opinion and/or personal preference what an individual "perceives" to be smoother. Again, not to say OP is not going to fall head over heels in love with your answer :)

Comment: thanks for the answer @PatrickSampaio There is only speed increased, I have researched about it and found that the smoothness can be better when using `transform:translate3d(0,0,0,)` may be that could do some smoothness

Answer (score 0):

I do not totally understand what smoothness you expect but i am convinced by seeing a lot of examples you can not get smoother animation with jquery compared to css. So I suggest you to use css transition.

following changes should work like a charm

```
//at CSS file
.mc-root {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    right:-100%;
}
.slide .mc-root{
  right:0;
}
//on your js place it whenever you want animation to happen
$('.main-outer').addClass("slide");
```

ease-in-out creates more natural animation.
and I suggest you to drop animation duration to 1 or 2 seconds. Most of the internet users are not interested in animations if they are too long and in my opinion its too long. But its your choice

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using only **CSS** `animation` property:

Set `right:0%;` and set keyframe from `right:-100%;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.main-outer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mc-root {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  right: 0%;
  animation: slideIn 2s ease;
}

@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    right: -100%;
  }
}

.leftcol {
  width: 130px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.leftcol>p {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.rightcol {
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  background: #666;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.rightcol>p {
  margin: 50px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-outer">
  <div class="mc-root">
    <div class="leftcol">
      <p>NAV</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcol">
      <p>MAIN Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```